# Что такое "псевдоним" для аргумента?

Tags: c#

Читаю *Джон Шарп - Microsoft Visual C#. Подробное руководство - 2017*.

Разбираю тему с **ref** и **out** и там встречается такое примечание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже второй, третий раз встречаю слово псевдоним.

***Собственно вопрос:*** что такое псевдоним для аргумента в данном контексте или псевдоним в целом.

Comment: Псевдоним - другое имя того же объекта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. «Обычные» параметры (без `ref`/`out`) передаются в метод *по значению*. Это значит, что если вы поменяете значение параметра внутри метода, то снаружи этого никто не заметит.

(Если вы поменяете не сам параметр ссылочного типа, а его поля/свойства, то это снаружи будет видно, но это уже другая история.)

Теперь, если у вас при параметре указан `ref`, то изменения этого параметра *станут видны снаружи*. То есть в коде

```
void Change(ref string s)
{
    s = "Хихи";
}

string abc = "abc";
Change(ref abc);
```

будет изменена не копия ссылки `abc` на строку, а сама эта ссылка. Поэтому если вы теперь напишете

```
Console.WriteLine(abc);
```

— то выведено будет именно `Хихи`.

Таким образом, имеется в виду, что `s` во время выполнения метода как бы просто *другое имя* (то есть, *псевдоним*) для имени `abc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Test(int a)
{
  // changes to "a" do not affect variable used in Test call
  // изменение значения параметра "a" не влияет на значение переменной,
  // использованной в качестве аргумента вызова функции
  a = a + 1;
}

public void TestRef(ref int a)
{
  // changes to "a" do affect variable used in TestRef call
  // изменение значения параметра "a" меняет значение переменной,
  // использованной в качестве аргумента вызова функции, отсюда - псевдоним
  a = a + 1;
}

public void TestOut(out int a)
{
  // changes to "a" do affect variable used in TestOut call,
  // value assigned to variable before the call is discarded
  // присвоение значения параметру "a" присваивает значение переменной,
  // использованной в качестве аргумента вызова функции, отсюда - псевдоним;
  // значение переменной до вызова функции теряется, 
  // переменая может быть не инициализирована до вызова функции

  // compiler error without this:
  // параметр обязательно должен быть инициализирован до 
  // использования/возврата
  a = 2;  
  a = a + 1;
}

int b = 5;
Test(b);     // b = 5
Test(ref b); // b = 6
Test(out b); // b = 3;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался в разнице обычного параметра, с ref и с out. Но вопрос заключался в другом. Если есть дополнения. Я выслушаю.